# Including hosted js and css in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to add hosted js and css to content_script chrome plugin.

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "css": ["bootstrap.min.css", "mystyles.css"],
      "js": ["jquery-1.7.2.min.js", "myscript.js"],
      "all_frames" : true
    }
  ]
```

here the js and css should be in the same package of manifest.json

I want to add hosted js like

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "css": ["bootstrap.min.css", "mystyles.css"],
      "js": ["https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js", "https://www.example.com/js/myscript.js"],
      "all_frames" : true
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, can't do that.

First things first, *never* use CDNs to deliver libraries like jQuery to your extension; there is literally no point, what are you saving? You get network latency where there shouldn't be one.

Next up, app logic scripts. I can understand a requirement to update them faster than you update the extension, then it makes sense. However, you can't include a non-local file like that in the manifest.

You can, however, do the following:

1. Inject a small "bootstrap" script, that is local.
2. [Message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) the [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) from the bootstrap script with request to inject the rest.
3. The background page fetches the script [with XHR](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr) (remember that you will need host permissions).

   I recommend using some sort of caching too, like only try to fetch a new version once every N minutes/hours/days and [saving a copy locally in `chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage). Otherwise, again, you'll get horrendous latency.
4. The background page injects the script using the

   ```
   chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {code: "..."})
   ```

   form of [programmatic injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript).

Do note that all of this is relatively complicated, and highly discouraged unless you use HTTPS to deliver scripts (otherwise you're wide open to MitM attacks). Unless you have a specific requirement to update app's logic faster than you can update the extension, don't do this.

Comment: Agree. There are some exceptions for example google discourages using a local analytics.js and instead suggests to inject it. I still dont :)